# Render apiary documentation locally with the V4 interactive documentation

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary

I would like to render API Blueprint documentation in the v4 interactive documentation format locally using apiary-cli or something similar.

I recently started using Apiary. Currently I am generating docs locally using apiary preview but this generates v3 documentation using the old interactive documentation views.

```sh
apiary preview --output=./reporting.html --path=./doc/reporting/reporting.apib
```

I would like to see the new view locally to check my changes before pushing changes to the remote docs view to everyone. Is there any way to view the v4 view without pushing to remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v4 is still in preview. We are in the stage of gathering feedback and progressively adding features to it. This one in particular isn't yet available, but it's on our roadmap.

Meanwhile you can use the online editor, via apiary.io, to preview your changes.